# VS code cannot tell what imported objects are

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, import

In one of my projects, I've made a separate file to test it out. When I import the classes from the first function (loot_tables.py) into the current file (test_loot_tables.py), I don't get any pop-ups for the dunder init. It can't even tell that the loot_tables object (which is a module) is a module. I'm in VS code using python version 3.9.1, and the classes I'm importing are dataclasses.

Comment: Can you post the output so the question is clearer?

Comment: Please provide more information available, preferably a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Albert_coding it isn't an error. The code will still run. But the issue is that I can't see any of the pop-ups.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out. Turns out, the folder the python file was in had the same name as the python file. So vscode tried to get the classes from the folder, and couldn't find them. Sorry!